# python formula get value from another sheet have space with python

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

Python can't accept formula with space in it.

Like this the 'original data' sheet

```
sheet.write_merge(0, 0, 5, 8, xlwt.Formula('IF(Original Data!B4<>"",Original Data!B4,"")'), center)
```

it will show error

if i use this

```
sheet.write_merge(0, 0, 5, 8, xlwt.Formula('IF('Original Data'!B4<>"",'Original Data'!B4,"")'), center)
```

it also show error

if i use this

```
sheet.write_merge(0, 0, 5, 8, xlwt.Formula("IF('Original Data'!B4<>"",'Original Data'!B4,"")"), center)
```

it also error

Is there a way to run the formula? I'll try any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: What's the error it's showing?

Comment: I'll add an error on the answer sheet

Comment: the formula means if there a value in the cell. then get the value from it. otherwise leave it blank

Comment: if u run the formula directly on excel. The second part is the working one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either escape the quotes in the string or else use triple quotes at the outer level like this:

```
sheet.write_merge(0, 0, 5, 8, xlwt.Formula("""IF('Original Data'!B4<>"",'Original Data'!B4,"")"""), center)
```

See the Python docs about [strings, quotes and escaping](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Answer (score 1):

```
sheet.write_merge(0, 0, 5, 8, xlwt.Formula('IF(Original Data!B4<>"",Original Data!B4,"")'), center)
```

error

```
raise ExcelFormulaParser.FormulaParseException, "can't parse formula " + s
FormulaParseException: can't parse formula IF(Original data!B3<>"";Original data!B3;"")
```

next

```
sheet.write_merge(0, 0, 5, 8, xlwt.Formula('IF('Original Data'!B4<>"",'Original Data'!B4,"")'), center)
```

error
[image]

next

```
sheet.write_merge(0, 0, 5, 8, xlwt.Formula("IF('Original Data'!B4<>"",'Original Data'!B4,"")"), center)
```

error

```
raise ExcelFormulaParser.FormulaParseException, "can't parse formula " + s
FormulaParseException: can't parse formula IF('Original data'!B3<>;'Original data'!B3;)
```